# Can't boot into the system after installing ubuntu 18.10 on my laptop

Tags: boot, windows-10, 18.10

[image: this is what i get after the installation is finished and i reboot.]
I have installed ubuntu via a usb stick. I followed to the letter according to the official tutorial on the ubuntu main site. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 everything went well as it should,  but when i reboot my laptop, it gives me the error in the picture. 
What can be the problem? 
My laptop is  acer e 15, and before i installed ubuntu, i had windows 10 professional.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you want to dual-boot, and keep Windows10.  Or remove Win 10 and only use Ubuntu?

Comment: i want to remove win 10, and use ubuntu. @JamesK